# How to prevent auto-sizing of ag-grid columns

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-column

I am using ag-grid with server-side row model. Column width is set calling ag-grid api explicitly. But when scrolling, as the grid loads more rows, the columns get resized on its own. How to prevent this? I want the grid not to auto-size columns on scrolling.

Comment: Usually this should not happen. I am working quite some time with ag-grid already and this never happened to me. However, we never used server-side row model. Are you using flex: 1? I assume this might be the problem and in order to stay fixed you need to configure fixed widths in the columnDefs without flex.

Comment: No. I am not using flex. But once the first set of data is loaded, I call autoSizeAllColumns(true) to set column widths as per cell contents ignoring header. This works fine. But as the grid is scrolled, more rows get loaded and the column widths get adjusted automatically.

Comment: Indeed we are not using autoSizeAllColumns(true) as in our experience, this did lead to unexpected behaviors...